# Error when try to use Docusign app in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to use Docusign by Salesforce1, and when click on the Docusign button is occurring an error:

```
Error Domain=DSAPIManager Code=1004 
"One or both of Username and Password are invalid." 
UserInfo={
  DS_API_MANAGER_ERRO_ID_KEY=USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, 
  NSLocalizedDescription=One or Both of Username and Password are invalid.,
  RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey=(
    "[DSAPIErrorResponse{
      message= One or both of Username or Password are invalid.;
      errorCode=USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED; error = (null); 
      }]
    ")
}
```

This is occuring in a mobile IPhone and for not for all users.
In debug log doesn't appearing anything and in the Docusign log too.
We are appointing the correct Docusign URL (NA2,NA3).

The steps that the user are doing is:
Log-in into Docusign app > authenticate with user and password> after logged he goes to the Salesforce1 > select an opportunity > click on Docusign button > select a document and a recipient > click on Docusign button.
After this process the error occurs.

Could someone help me?

Thanks
Rafael

Answer (score 0):

1. When you login to the DocuSign Mobile app they login to one user - but your Salesforce Org actually  has them synced with another user.
2. Or your user has some recipient accounts that need to be closed probably a Force User Sync after in DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce.

The steps that the user are doing is: Log-in into Docusign app > authenticate with user and password> after logged he goes to the Salesforce1 > select an opportunity > click on Docusign button > select a document and a recipient > click on Docusign button. After this process the error occurs.
You would also need to make sure they choose the right server/environment for that first step.

Comment: HI Inbar,
I did the Force Sync and the user tested with the https://na2.docusign.net and https://na3.docusign.net URL, but he received the same error.

Comment: You would have to contact our support as this is a specific issue we would need to work with you on that.

Comment: Hi Inbar,
Could you share with me a contact that could help us inside of Docusign?
Or specific department?

Comment: are you using production , paid account? or is this for developer account in demo?

Comment: I'm using paid account, this is in production.

Comment: in that case, please go to https://support.docusign.com and open a support ticket.